# How do I convert c struct from dll to C#

Tags: c#, dll, struct, dllimport

I am converting a application from c++ to C# and have a question about the proper way to handle importing structs. I am attempting to convert a struct from a c dll into c#  The struct in c looks like this

```
typedef struct card_info
{
  ushort r;
  ushort s;
  enum_a a;
  usinged long ul;
  ushort n;
  ushort* b;
  ushort id;
} CARD_INFO;
```

when i use [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequentaial)]  the size of the array is 20 bytes in c#.  However, if take a look at my working c++ code it is 24 bytes.  I changed my c# to look like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CardInfo
{
  [FieldOffset(0) public ushort r;
  [FieldOffset(2) public ushort s;
  [FieldOffset(4) public EnumA a;
  [FieldOffset(8) public ushort ul;
  [FieldOffset(12) public ushort n;
  [FieldOffset(16) public UInt32 b;
  [FieldOffset(20) public ushort id;
}
```

This seems to compile but I'm not convinced this is the correct way to go about doing this.  Please let me know if this is correct or if there is a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
usinged long ul;
```

It's a typo, but that definitely isn't a ushort, it's an uint.

Don't use FieldOffset either, let the compiler figure it out.  Now Marshal.SizeOf() will return 24, the proper amount of padding is inserted.  The `b` member should be IntPtr btw.

Answer (score 1):

@**Hans's** answer is correct, but I'll just add some tips on debugging marshalled data so you can see the results. I just instantiate a structure and create a pointer to it like this.

```
CardInfo cardInfo = new CardInfo();
IntPtr pointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(cardInfo));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(cardInfo, pointer, false);
```

Stick a breakpoint on the last line of this and step into the debugger until it breaks. You should see the `pointer` in the locals/autos windows, and it's value should be some int value. (Hex display works best here).

[image: Img1]

Move over to the Command window, and type `dc 0x0086bf30` <- the address of your pointer. It should dump out the data in that are of memory. Typing `dc` again will dump the next chunks of memory. You can also use `da`, `db`, `dd`, `df`, `dq` to dump the data as different types. Try stepping over the breakpoint next (F10), and dump the same memory again.

[image: Img2]

You can initialize the fields of your struct with particular values and observe the changes here to see if it's working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

`ul` is an unsigned long in the C implementation but you're using an unsigned short. That would be a good place to start, if you're wondering why your `StructLayout.Sequential` implementation is too small.

I'd also double check your `EnumA` implementation to make sure it's the right size.