# how to pass a pointer to C# struct to a method in C

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I want to use a c++ dll in c#. I'm using `[DllImport]` to call the method. I'm having trouble passing struct to a method.

I have a C struct:

```
typedef struct
{
DWORD TopPoint;
DWORD EndPoint;
WORD dwCount;
MYFUNC_NUMERIC11 *pGetData;
} MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL;
```

`MYFUNC_NYMERIC11` is another struct.

```
typedef struct
{
BYTE Sign; // Sign ("±")
BYTE Integer[3]; // 3-digit integer (no zero suppression)
BYTE Period; // Decimal point (".")
BYTE Decimal[6]; // 6-digit decimal number
} MYFUNC_NUMERIC11;
```

I have written a C# struct to mimic this.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public unsafe struct MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL
{
    public uint TopPoint;
    public uint EndPoint;
    public ushort Count;
    public IntPtr pGetData;
}
```

A pointer to the struct is an argument in a method. C# function is:

```
[DllImport("MYFUNC_DLL.dll", EntryPoint = "MYFUNC_GetData", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
public static extern int MYFUNC_GetData(IntPtr myfuncHandle, UInt32 dwIO, ref IntPtr pBufferNormal, Byte bccFlg);
```

This is the method in C:

```
MYFUNC_STATUS MYFUNC_GetData(MYFUNC_HANDLE myfuncHandle, DWORD dwOut, MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL *pBufferNormal , BYTE bccFlg)
```

The return type is cast to an enum, which has an interpretation. The struct parameter is invalid. I've tried to allocate memory using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal(...)`, but the parameter is still invalid, i.e. there is no error during compilation but the value returned is incorrect.

I've spent quite a few hours on this, still unable to figure out what to do. A lot of similar questions exist already, like here: [How do I convert c struct from dll to C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4587793/15740324) or here: [How to pass C# array to C++ and return it back to C# with additional items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7624561/15740324), but I, somehow, still haven't figured out a way.

Comment: This isn't _"COM-interop"_ but rather _p-invoke_

Comment: [`Marshal.StructureToPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr?view=net-5.0)

Comment: You are calling with windows convention instead of c language : CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl

Comment: `ref IntPtr pBufferNormal` is not correct, remove *ref*.  Or better yet, make it ref MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL so you don't have marshal everything yourself.  The dwCount member strongly suggests that you can use MYFUNC_NUMERIC11[] pGetData.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I'm trying to use that. Unsuccessfully so, might I add.

Comment: @jdweng Is there anything wrong with that? It's served me well so far. Would love to know more.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't have the dll source code, so I can't say for sure. But I can try this.

Comment: Yes.  Windows calling convention for methods the parameter list gets put into the execution stack different from c language calling convention.  So if you are using a Fortran or basic compiler you use CallingConvention.StdCall.

Comment: It's not 100% clear from the limited code provided here which calling convention the DLL function uses. We can't say for sure which it is, you need to check that carefully in the DLL header file.

Comment: C or C++ DLL could (should?) be linked as stdcall ones though so it could have either calling convention.

Comment: The DLL uses `CallingConvention.StdCall`. I tried using `CallingConvention.CDecLl` and it threw an unbalanced stack error.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/8719 shame thi has not been implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, at least with one element in the array (is it an array?). For an array, you will have to allocate `sizeof * count` of elements and marshal (StructureToPtr) each element at its offset.

```
var num = new MYFUNC_NUMERIC11();
num.Integer = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
num.Decimal = new byte[] { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
num.Sign = 10;
num.Period = 11;

var buffer = new MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL();
buffer.Count = 1234;
buffer.EndPoint = 5678;
buffer.TopPoint = 9;
buffer.pGetData = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(num));
try
{
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(num, buffer.pGetData, false);
    MYFUNC_GetData(Whatever, 0, ref buffer, 0);
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer.pGetData);
}
```

With these definitions.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL
{
    public uint TopPoint;
    public uint EndPoint;
    public ushort Count;
    public IntPtr pGetData;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MYFUNC_NUMERIC11
{
    public byte Sign;
    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public byte[] Integer;
    
    public byte Period;
    
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 6)]
    public byte[] Decimal;
}

// check calling convention
[DllImport(@"MYFUNC_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern MYFUNC_STATUS  MYFUNC_GetData(IntPtr myfuncHandle, uint dwIO, ref MYFUNC_BUFFERNORMAL pBufferNormal, byte bccFlg);
```

Comment: I actually have an array of elements, so `sizeof * count` was my way to go. I tried this for a single element, and looks good so far. FYI: my calling convention was `StdCall`. The convention you suggested `Cdecl` was not supported by the DLL I am using.